# Slack API not sending message events for file_shared events

Tags: javascript, slack-api

I am building an app which uses the Slack Bolt framework to interact with a Slack workspace.  As part of this I need to be able to take action when a user uploads/shares a file in a channel.  This can be done by setting up a listener for the message sub type of file_share.

Currently I am using the following javascript to setup the listener to log any message events:

```
slackApp.event("message", async ({ event, body, say, client, logger }) => {
  logger.info("!!Received an file share message:\n" + JSON.stringify(event));
  }
```

This works for any files shared via a DM but not when a user shares a file to a channel.

I am sure that scopes/permissions are set correctly for this to work.

[Slack Bot Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cg19.png)